# Meteor: How to count some data in collection?

Tags: meteor

I've a problem to count some data in a collection. This code is not working for me. Can anyone help me?

Client code:

```
Template.count_status.helpers({
    countcategory: function(){
        return Profil.find({
            status: 'Available',
            category: { $in: ['PTR', 'KOM'] },
        }).count();
    }
});
```

Server Code:

```
Meteor.methods({
    countcategory: function () {
        return Profil.find().count();
    }
});
```

Comment: did you call the server method in client?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have subscribed to "profil" collection(client side). And it is published in the server code. I presume that you are not using pub/sub functions.

Make sure autopublish package is added to your package (for client side code mentioned to work).

You are not using Server code pasted above.

You can call server method using below code:

```
Template.count_status.helpers({
    countcategory: function(){
        Meteor.call('countcategory', function(err,res){
            if(err){
                //do something with err
            }
            else{
                //do something with result
            }
        });
    }
});
```